# Taking full Input dataset when testing transformations in Palantir Foundry

Tags: unit-testing, pyspark, palantir-foundry

In Palantir Foundry, I could see that we can write unit tests using Pytest or TransformRunner. My understanding is that, with Pytest we cannot pass an output of transform for unit testing and in TransformRunner we cannot use the dataset that we have to use originally. We need some test data. But I would like to use the whole input dataset on which my transform should run in production and do run tests on the output of it. How can I achieve that?

Comment: For those voting this question to be closed, if you are aware of how Palantir Foundry works, this is just specific enough, but I understand where you are coming from. @DR_S you have too low rep to see it, but your question already has 2 close votes for "Community Specific - needs debugging info". To avoid these situations in stack overflow I would recommend that you expand your question with some code examples of what you have been trying.

Comment: To define unit tests, you need to build your input dataset to ensure you will run your tests on stable and constant data. Actually, it does not really make sense to run tests with production data, because these data might change and you will not be able to predict (assess) the result (you are supposed to be able to run your test during your development phase, but also later on if any updates are made to ensure there are no regression bugs).  
Therefore, you definitely need to think of building test cases depending on your functional context and build a test dataset accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You can't access foundry datasets from the CI, you'll need to have the data snippet in a  file within your repo and then load it.

test/fixtures/data/input/a.csv

```
col_a,col_b
1,2
```

```py
TEST_DATA_DIR = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), '..', '..', 'fixtures', 'data')


def test_runner_single_table(spark_session):
    pipeline = Pipeline()

    @transform_df(Output('/test_single_table/output/test'),
                  input_a=Input('/test_single_table/input/a'))
    def transform_1(input_a):
        return input_a.withColumn('col_c', input_a['col_a'] + input_a['col_b'])

    pipeline.add_transforms(transform_1)

    runner = TransformRunner(pipeline, '/test_single_table', TEST_DATA_DIR)

    output = runner.build_dataset(spark_session, '/test_single_table/output/test')
    assert output.first()['col_c'] == 3
```

`TransformsRunner` will translate the `Input` path into the directory path. In the example above:

- `TEST_DATA_DIR` tells the runner where the data is in your environment
- `'/test_single_table'` tells the runner what subpath can be ignored, since this path only exists on foundry datasets, not within your repo
- `input/a` will be resolved against the `Input('[ignored_sub_path]/input/a')` and folder structure you defined in your repo.

You can print this properties and it will show up in the CI checks, if you want to understand them better.