# How to test a transformation in Palantir Foundry?

Tags: unit-testing, apache-spark, pyspark, palantir-foundry, foundry-code-repositories

We try to create a test function for the whole transformation.

```py
import os
from transforms.verbs.testing.TransformRunner import TransformRunner
from transforms.api import Pipeline
from .myproject.datasets import my_transform

# This assumes your test data exists in the folder /test/fixtures/data/ within the repo next to this test
TEST_DATA_DIR = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'fixtures', 'data')

def test_my_transform(spark_session):
    pipeline = Pipeline()
    pipeline.add_transforms(my_transform)

    runner = TransformRunner(pipeline, '/my_fabulous_project', TEST_DATA_DIR)

    output = runner.build_dataset(spark_session, '/my_fabulous_project/output/test')
    assert output.first()['col_c'] == 3
```

Based on the documentation and [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70570164/taking-full-input-dataset-when-testing-transformations-in-palantir-foundry#70765939), we tried to modify the import of the function, but we always get one of these errors:

> transforms._errors.TransformTypeError: Expected arguments to be of type <class 'transforms.api._transform.Transform'>

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'test.myproject'

> ValueError: attempted relative import beyond top-level package

How to create a working end-to-end testing function for a transformation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After trying out several approaches with different conditions, the following approach seems cleanest to me.

- no hard-coding paths to datasets
- it is very explicit about adding/removing transformation inputs
- in-memory dataframes are used as test inputs

`test_my_transform.py`

```py
from transforms.api import Pipeline
from transforms.verbs.testing.TransformRunner import TransformRunner
from transforms.verbs.testing.datastores import InMemoryDatastore
from myproject.datasets.my_transform import compute_sum


def test_compute_sum(spark_session):

    df_input1 = spark_session.createDataFrame([
        (0, 2)
    ], ['col_a', 'col_b'])

    df_input2 = spark_session.createDataFrame([
        (0, 1)
    ], ['col_a', 'col_b'])

    df_expected = spark_session.createDataFrame([
        (0, 1, 1),
        (0, 2, 2)
    ], ['col_a', 'col_b', 'col_c'])

    # If @transform_df or @transform_pandas, the key is 'bound_output'
    # If @transform, the key is the name of variable Output
    output_map = {'out': df_expected}
    input_map = {
        'input_a': df_input1,
        'input_b': df_input2,
    }

    pipeline = Pipeline()
    pipeline.add_transforms(compute_sum)
    store = InMemoryDatastore()
    for inp_name, inp_obj in pipeline.transforms[0].inputs.items():
        store.store_dataframe(inp_obj.alias, input_map[inp_name])
    path_out = pipeline.transforms[0].outputs[list(output_map)[0]].alias
    runner = TransformRunner(pipeline, datastore=store)
    df_out = runner.build_dataset(spark_session, path_out)

    assert df_out.subtract(df_expected).count() == 0
    assert df_expected.subtract(df_out).count() == 0
    assert df_out.schema == df_expected.schema
```

`my_transform.py`

```py
from transforms.api import Input, Output, transform
from pyspark.sql import functions as F


@transform(
    out=Output('/some_foundry_path/my_dir/out3'),
    input_a=Input('/some_foundry_path/my_dir/in'),
    input_b=Input('/some_foundry_path/my_dir/in2'))
def compute_sum(input_a, input_b, out):
    input_a = input_a.dataframe()
    input_b = input_b.dataframe()
    df = input_a.unionByName(input_b)
    df = df.withColumn('col_c', F.col('col_a') + F.col('col_b'))
    out.write_dataframe(df)
```

Answer (score 3):

The following transformation tests work for functions decorated both with `@transform` and `@transform_df`.

`my_transform.py` is located in the repository in `src/myproject/datasets` folder.

```py
from transforms.api import Input, Output, transform_df
from pyspark.sql import functions as F


@transform_df(
    Output('/some_foundry_path/my_dir/out'),
    input_a=Input('/some_foundry_path/my_dir/in'))
def compute_sum(input_a):
    df = input_a.withColumn('col_c', F.col('col_a') + F.col('col_b'))
    return df
```

Input file:
[image]

**Approach where test inputs are stored in-memory**

`test_my_transform.py` is located in the repository in `src/test` folder.

```py
from transforms.api import Pipeline
from transforms.verbs.testing.TransformRunner import TransformRunner
from transforms.verbs.testing.datastores import InMemoryDatastore
from myproject.datasets.my_transform import compute_sum


def test_compute_sum(spark_session):

    df_in = spark_session.createDataFrame([
        (0, 1)
    ], ['col_a', 'col_b'])

    df_expected = spark_session.createDataFrame([
        (0, 1, 1)
    ], ['col_a', 'col_b', 'col_c'])

    path_in = '/some_foundry_path/my_dir/in'
    path_out = '/some_foundry_path/my_dir/out'

    pipeline = Pipeline()
    pipeline.add_transforms(compute_sum)
    store = InMemoryDatastore()
    store.store_dataframe(path_in, df_in)
    runner = TransformRunner(pipeline, datastore=store)
    df_out = runner.build_dataset(spark_session, path_out)

    assert df_out.subtract(df_expected).count() == 0
    assert df_expected.subtract(df_out).count() == 0
    assert df_out.schema == df_expected.schema
```

`path_in` and `path_out` are exactly the same as the Input and Output paths of the transformation. So it's easy to follow this script.

**Approach where test inputs are stored in .csv in repository**

This approach is in the official documentation. It is more elaborate, not so easy to understand what paths should be created, and it may be hard to maintain: in case dataset path changes, a new repository tree might be needed to create.

`test_my_transform.py` is located in the repository in `src/test` folder.

```py
from transforms.api import Pipeline
from transforms.verbs.testing.TransformRunner import TransformRunner
import os
from myproject.datasets.my_transform import compute_sum

# Taking this .py file's dir and appending the path to the test data
TEST_DATA_DIR = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'fixtures/data/input')


def test_compute_sum(spark_session):

    path_in_prefix = '/some_foundry_path/my_dir'
    path_out = '/some_foundry_path/my_dir/out'

    pipeline = Pipeline()
    pipeline.add_transforms(compute_sum)
    runner = TransformRunner(pipeline, path_in_prefix, TEST_DATA_DIR)
    df_out = runner.build_dataset(spark_session, path_out)

    assert df_out.head()['col_c'] == 1
```

Test CSV file (`in.csv` - it has the same name `in` as transformation Input) is created inside the repository:
[image: test file inside repository]

```
col_a,col_b
0,1
```

Note:

> *for all the inputs*
>
> > Input path (*`/some_foundry_path/my_dir/in`*)
> > less
> > `path_in_prefix` (*`/some_foundry_path/my_dir/`*)
>
> **should be equal to**
>
> > CSV test file full path (*`...src/test/fixtures/data/input/in`*)
> > less
> > `TEST_DATA_DIR` (*`...src/test/fixtures/data/input`*)

---

**To make tests run automatically together with checks**, uncomment the following line in `transforms-python/build.gradle`:

[image]

Comment: Is there a way to not have to reference a local file when testing but instead being able to create a dataframe in memory manually?

Comment: You can swap out the on-disk datastore that backs the `TransformRunner` with an in-memory one.  

Import: `from transforms.verbs.testing.datastores import InMemoryDatastore`  

Create: `in_memory_store = InMemoryDatastore()`  

Populate: `in_memory_store.store_dataframe("<dataset_alias>", df)`  

Use: `runner = TransformRunner(datastore=in_memory_store)`

Comment: Thanks, @RyanNorris. We've tested your suggestion and it looks far better than the "official" one. I've added it to this answer as the first (preferred) approach.

Comment: @luk2302 - I've complemented the answer with the option to create in-memory test dataframes. Thanks for this invaluable remark. This approach looks simpler in several ways.

Comment: @RyanNorris - could you please comment on how to use several in-memory inputs?

Comment: @ZygD can you ask that as a new question and we'll answer there?

Comment: @ZygD you should be able to just call `store.store_dataframe(<alias>, <dataframe>)` once for each of your inputs.